# Dog with leg wound escapes cone and bites leg

Tags: dogs, safety, injury, wound-care

Our dog has a wound in the right front leg (nothing severe). In order to treat it, a cone of shame (normal plastic one) is being used, together with a specific spray. For reference, the cone looks similar to this one

[image]

The spray does what it's intended to, but the healing takes time. Thing is, in its "free time" the dog (without us nearby) is able to break out of the cone and then goes and bites the leg again, making the healing process take longer.

How to proceed in this situation?

Comment: How long is the dog in "free time"? From the answer depends how durable the solution need to be

Comment: @Allerleirauh the longest part is through the night -> around 8 hours

Comment: How does he get out of the cone? Can he slip his head through the collar or does he somehow remove the cone from the collar? If he slips the collar over his head, you can either tighten the collar or try using a wider collar.

Comment: @Elmy its a combination of moves. In the garden we have a passion fruit "tree" covering part of the wall. By rubbing there it gets to loosen it. Other times goes with the cone against specific locations to break the cone. Other times rubs the cone area in the floor, while nearly rolling in the floor. All in all, it has all the procedures to open (and even crack) the cone.

Comment: Then maybe you could try covering the wound instead of putting a cone on him. Although I doubt that he won't be able to remove the covering as well... Another idea is bitter apple extract (you should be able to get it in a pharmacy or from a vet and in very rare cases from pet or drug stores). Apply a drop of the extract around the wound, but not directly on the wound. As the name implies it tastes bitter and discourages licking.

Comment: We tried to cover before and it was removed... but what we didn't was the combination with cover and bitter apple extract. That might work indeed together with the cone still (to give less opportunity to think about going there)

Comment: I know people, that let their dog wear a bathing suit, if the wound is on the back or belly. Maybe you could use a big sock and make it really fixed on a harness, so the whole leg is covered. this would allow smooth scratching for comfort, but would probably protect the wound from become open again... and maybe you could switch between some options, so the dog will not get used to one, and over stressed areas (for example the neck when wearing a cone) can have a rest